# jquery dragtable dynamically added column drag option not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.drag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dragndrop.table.columns.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            function initDraggable(c){
               $(c).dragtable({dragaccept:'.dragdone',dragHandle:'.handle'});
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('coladd').ondblclick = function(){
            $("#tabdrag thead tr").eq(0).append("<th class=\"dragdone\"><div class=\"handle\"></div>three</th>");
            $("#tabdrag tbody tr").eq(1).append("<td>col3text5</td>");
            $("#tabdrag tbody tr").eq(2).append("<td>col3text6</td>");
             initDraggable($("#tabdrag"));
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id='coladd'>add column</p>
    <table id='tabdrag'>
    <thead><tr><th class='dragdone'><div class='handle'>one</div></th><th class='dragdone'><div class='handle'>two</div></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>col1text1</td><td>col2text2</td></tr><tr><td>col1text3</td><td>col2text4</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamically i add column after add drag option not working before add its working fine.please help me any one
i call function initDraggable after dynamically add column its not working
and also another question how to include library file to dynamically add part

Answer (score 2):

This answer is coming super late, but you can make new, dynamically added columns draggable with this:

```
$('.defaultTable').dragtable('destroy').dragtable({});
```